# List the categories an entry is part of?

Tags: categories

I'm new to all of this and so far Categories from a templating point of view are confusing me a bit. I'm loving Craft so far but some concepts are causing me some headaches to adjust to!

What i'm trying to do is list the sub-categories a blog post is part of.

I have 6 categories and each has 4 sub-categories.
I only want to list the sub-categories.

So when someone is viewing the site and they click into a full blog post page, at the top i'm listing the title, author, posted date and i want to follow that with a lisrt of the sub-categories applied to that blog post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will list all the categories that are assigned to the entry regardless of level.

```
<ul>
    {% for category in entry.categoriesFieldHandle %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.url }}">category.title</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you only want to list the subcategories, (regardless of whether a main category is also assigned) then you can add a test for the category level.

```
<ul>
    {% for category in entry.categoriesFieldHandle %}
        {% if category.level > 1 %}
            <li><a href="{{ category.url }}">category.title</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I would actually include the level argument in the for loop. That field is just an element criteria model until you actually run it. Something like this: `{% for category in entry.categoriesFieldHandle.level(1) %}`

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks to both of you :^) I combined your methods (changing level(1) to level('> 1') to get sub-categories in the loop) and it works a charm!

Comment: Great! That works too. I wasn't sure if you maybe wanted to something slightly different with each level.